# opening a different webpage from my webpage and reading its content /clicking buttons etc

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was just curious as how to do this.

I want to open www.whatsmyip.com or something similar from my webpage.

Put an ip address in the textbox in that page.

Click the button

And read the value (suppose a textbox).

I want to achieve all this programatically without any human interaction.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

The example you posted is *not* possible.

You can't read the contents of a frame from another domain(though a subdomain or on the same domain is possible), this is a restriction known as the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), put in place for security reasons.

What If I could launch `gmail.com` and read your login name, what about your online banking site? :)  You can see how this would be quickly abused if allowed.

Comment: You've practically singlehandedly exhausted my supply of upvotes for today.

Comment: Thanks for info.i never knew abt same origin policy..
but we can write some covert scripts to simulate the events..i sound like a freak.but i wud try out writing some scripts to simulate :).thnx

Comment: @sajad - You mean get the IP from javascript? No that isn't possible, you can proxy content through your server or hit an external service using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) though, but you can't get this informationg strictly from the client...nor would it be accurate with NAT and such, e.g. my local IP is not my external IP.